# python paste multilines to raw_input in a while loop

Tags: python, raw-input

I have some code looks like this:

```
while line != '' and line != 'STOP ME':
    line = raw_input("")
    buf.append(line+'\n')

sys.stdin.flush()
print raw_input("Input1:")
print raw_input("Input2:")
```

The problem is, if the user copy and paste the data like this

> line1
>
> line2
>
> STOP ME
>
> "empty line"
>
> "empty line"
>
> Some junk text

My raw_input will be overflowed with junk text after "STOP ME". Is there a way to avoid it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

May be you don't need `raw_input` here? You can use `sys.stdin` file-like object. For example `sys.stdin.read` method.

Or you can use somthing like this:

```
buf.append(line.split('STOP ME\n', 1)[0]+'\n')
```

to get data before `STOP ME` line.

Comment: I know using sys.stdin.read may avoid the problem I have, but I'm afraid the users will forget how to terminate input... Even if I remind the user to use "Ctrl-D" in the beginning, if the text is longer than one screen, they will most likely not see the text.

Comment: Thanks for the update! but I don't think this will help me. There is nothing wrong with the content in buf, but rather there are unfinished stdin which will cause the program not stopping at "Input1:" and "Input2:".

Comment: I think sys.stdin.read is the closest solution to this problem. Also, I just learned to terminate stdin.read() in Windows, I need to press Ctrl-Z + Enter, while in Linux, a single Ctrl-D is sufficient.